# How to cut a 2D triangle mesh by a polyline?

Tags: c++, graphics, geometry, 2d

Given a 2D triangle mesh (.obj) with hole(s),
I want to cut the mesh by a polyline (as red curve in image below) to produce two separate meshes.

As additional info, the polyline is open curve.

[image]

[image]

Is there any algorithm to do this?

I tried to google this problem but I only found mesh cutting by a single line or by a plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used CGAL's [AABB tree](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html) and the [Polyhedron](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/index.html) data structure, to do something similar to what you just asked. But I had to do the actual cutting *i.e.* creating new vertices, adding new edges etc, were all figured out by me (or my teammates). And the CGAL library came in very handy for doing this.

The basic method was to use the AABB tree to figure out all the intersections between the line (or set of lines, in case of a polyline) and the mesh. You'll be able to get the intersections in a specific order from CGAL. Then you walk along them one after another, adding the new edges and vertices. Normally you don't have to add new vertices except at the start and end points.

The CGAL Polyhedron API supports dividing polygons along edges, which you can use as you walk along the result set. Internally, it uses a [half edge](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/HalfedgeDS/index.html) data structure, which supports these operations from the get go.

Comment: Can you use CGAL to detect if an edge is inside triangle, outside, on the border?

Comment: CGAL's AABB data st. will give the list of faces that intersect with the polyline. Additionally it can also provide the exact points of intersection. The list of points will match with the list of faces one-one. So you should be able to figure out where the edges (connecting the points) lie exactly. Please look at the API documentation for more info.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, I think it's feasible, thanks.
But I notice that AABB tree in CGAL is only in 3D, FYI, my triangle mesh is 2D